# My Ajax request throws an error in django, how do I find what it is?

Tags: ajax, django, django-errors

#### How do I get more information about the errors in my Ajax requests?

When error occurs in Django during a **normal HTTP request**, Django shows a **descriptive error page** with exception details.

However, when error occurs during an **AJAX request**, I just know the HTTP error code and that's it. I'd like to know **as much details** as I learn from a Django error page.

Comment: instead of editing the question, you should probably post an answer yourself..

Comment: But the answer's not completely mine, Ignacio led me to it.

Comment: if you feel Ignacio's reply **answers the question** (and might help anyone else with the same problem), mark it as accepted and include any clarifications (e.g. what you learned from the logs) in a comment to that answer. Right now your question looks like a mess—a mix of your question, Ignacio's answer and something else. **If you feel Ignacio's answer is not enough**, just create your own answer and describe the exact solution (and don't forget to give credits to Ignacio in the text :-). It's perfectly fine to answer your own questions.

Comment: I edited your question to make it more StackOverflow-ish. Please don't include **answers** in the **question**, they don't belong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web server's error log will contain additional information about any uncaught exceptions.

Comment: How do i access my server's log in django ?

Comment: You don't. You ssh into the server and view it there.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm sorry I don't know how to do it. I'm running the server using the command - "manage.py runserver".

Comment: Can i somehow access the django error page, by tweaking either the JS or Python ?

Comment: The terminal shows a HTTP 200 code, but my jquery Ajax call executes the error function

Comment: The problem was that, I was supposed to return JSON and I was returning HTML

Answer (score 3):

Handle errors within your ajax request and use responseText to get the response text and put it into an empty div that you have created for that.

For example:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"{% yourView %}",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(jsonData){
            alert("Hooray!");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            $('.errors_div').html(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
```

The django error page will be rendered into div class=errors_div

Answer (score 0):

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). In Console you'll see the AJAX request, just right click -> Copy Response Content and save that as an HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Why not access the url directly in your browser's address bar so you see a normal traceback?

Wrap it in another view to change the MIME type to text/html.

I also often have a view that wraps the JSON output in a html tag so the Django Debug Toolbar works correctly.